# fgets() trouble. When getting user input for if/else statements

Tags: c

I am new to c programming. When i take the user input, lets say they put 1, it skips to invalid. This only happens when I try using the fgets(), when I use scanf it works fine. Could anyone help me out and possibly explain why this is happening so I can try to figure out how to fix it?

```
int main()
{
char choice [10];
printf ("Select an option: \n");
printf ("1. String -> numerical values \n");
printf ("2. Decimal values -> String \n");
printf ("3. Exit \n");
printf ("Enter a choice: \n"); 
fgets (choice, 10, stdin);

if (choice[10] == '1')
{
printf ("Please enter a string: ");
}

else if (choice[10] == '2')
{
    printf ("Convert ASCII decimal values to string (press ENTER after each integer). \n");
    printf ("Press ENTER twice to finish");

}

else if (choice[10] == '3')
{
    exit(0);
}
else 
{
    printf ("Invalid option \n");
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (choice[10] == '1')` breaks the array bounds. Did you mean `choice[0]`? You are not comparing a string (which isn't done like that) but should check its first character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your `if`s is that you are trying to access memory out of
bound, for an array of dimension 10, you can only access from 0 - 9, anything
beyound that yields undefined behaviour.

```
char choice [10];
...
if(choice[0] == '1')
{
    ...
}
```

In most programming languages, you start counting at 0. So if you declare an
array of dimension *n*, the first element is at position 0 and the last at
position *n-1*.

If you however want to compare strings, you should use `strcmp`. Note also that
`fgets` saves the newline when there is enough space in the buffer.

> *man fgets*
>
> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> `fgets()`  reads  in  **at  most  one less than `size` characters from stream** and stores them into the buffer pointed to by `s`.
>   Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer**.
>   A terminating null byte (`'\0'`)  is  stored  after  the last character in the buffer.

Comparing strings in your case:

```
if(strcmp(choice, "1\n") == 0)
{
    // string is equal to "1\n"
}
```

Comment: If he only cares about 1 digit, you can get away without using strcmp(), but the comparison has to be `if (choice[0] == '1')...`

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker you're right, I added that in the answer. But I also think that explaining how to compare strings in general is not bad either.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out with understanding what i was doing wrong :D